# Issue on Ordering - Indexing Multidimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at following demo let me know how I can force Javascript to push the items into the array based on the items id?

```js
var theArray = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["D", "E"],
    ["F", "G", "H", "I"],
    ["J"],
    ["K", "L", "M"]
];
var res = theArray.toString();

$('#textarea').text(res);

$("input[name='m1']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var selected = $(this).val();        
        theArray[1][id] = selected;
        
    } else {
        var itemtoRemove = $(this).val();
    theArray[1].splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, theArray[1]),1);

    }
    var res = theArray.toString();
$('#textarea').text(res);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br />
<textarea id="textarea" rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<fieldset>
    <legend>Items</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="m1" value="mItem1" />mItem 1
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="m1" value="mItem2" />mItem 2
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="m1" value="mItem3" />mItem 3
    <br />
    <br />
</fieldset>
```

As you can see the example works if you un check from `mItem 3` to `mItem 3` but if you uncheck `mItem 1` first and check it again it will overwrite the mitem2 in the array (which make seance!)

Can you please let me know how i can fix this?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? What do you expect from your snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the purpose of such an application, but if I understand your case correctly, here is the reason.

Initially the array is ["D", "E"].

When you check mItem3, it becomes ["D", "E", "", "mItem3"]. JS adds an empty item at index 2 because you are inserting at index 3.

When you uncheck mItem3, the array becoms ["D", "E", ""].

Check mItem2, then ["D", "E", "mItem2"].

Check mItem1, then it will replace the element at index 1 -> ["D", "mItem1", "mItem2"].

Uncheck mItem1 will remove mItem1 (at index 1) -> ["D", "mItem2"].

I think, it is all OK up to now for you.

Here the problem arises.

When you check mItem1 again, it replaces the item at index 1 whose value is "mItem2". So, naturally the array becomes ["D", "mItem1"].